# Confirming a successful LINQ to SQL update

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL). Is the following code proper if I want to notify the sender that the database was updated successfully or is there a better way?

```
           try
           {
               dc.ModelA.InsertOnSubmit(modela);
               dc.SubmitChanges();
               return true;
           }

           catch
           {
               return false;
           }
```

Comment: Don't you mean "a successful Linq to Sql Insert"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way is to not catch the exception and let it propagate to the caller. By catching the exception you are removing all information about *why* the insert failed, making it very hard for anyone to debug and fix the problem. So you just need this:

```
dc.ModelA.InsertOnSubmit(modela);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner approach would be to wrap it in  [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx):

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   dc.ModelA.InsertOnSubmit(modela);
   dc.SubmitChanges();
   scope.Complete();
}
```